# positioning element to float right & left + unclickable a tag

Tags: html, css, css-position

here is a screenshot of my website i want to adjust the image to be on the right of the page as indicated by the arrow below(`float:right;` didn't work).Also, as for (`float:left;`) i want on the left side to add some text as shown in the image below at the left side.Lastly for the circled part on the photo it is not clickable for some reason :(((
[image]
i want the picture to stick to the right side of the page as the arrow showing below::
[image]

the css code ::

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.header{
   height: 80px;
 width: 100%;
    background: url(images/header.jpeg);
    position: fixed;
}
.bar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 43px;
    background: url(images/menu-boarder.jpeg);
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.hp_div{
    background-color: pink;
}
.hp_div section#hpimg{
    float: left;
}
.hp_div section#hptext{
    float: right;
}
.menu{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 10px;

}
.menu li{
    display: inline-block;

}
.menu li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;

}
.menu li a:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    padding: 43px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 7px;
  position: relative;
  right:80px;


}

.searchTerm {
  width: 400%;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 20px;
}

.searchTerm:focus{
  color: #000000;
}


.searchButton {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background: #000000;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.fa-shopping-cart, .glyphicon-user{

    color: #000000;

}

.form-inline {
   display: flex;

}

.homeage_but {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.mark_colour{
    background-color: pink;
}
.container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
    background-color: pink;
}
.Hsection{margin-top:0px!important;margin-bottom:0px!important}
 .Hcontent{max-width:980px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}
.centered-element{text-align:center;}

.footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(images/footer.jpeg);
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

the html code::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--F04 :moudhi al.gowiez-->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>Cookie|Bakery shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="header">
        </div>
    <br><br><br><br>
 <div class="bar">
        <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Product</a></li>
        </ul>



      <div class="search">
         <form class="form-inline">
              <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
              <button type="submit" class="searchButton"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> 
            </form>  
     <div class="icons">
     <a herf=""><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="font-size:36px; margin-right: 10px;"></i></a>
     <a herf=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="font-size:30px; margin-right: 5px; "></i></a>
     </div>
     </div>


     </div>


    <div  class="footer">


    </div>
    <div class="hp_div">    

         <!-- Slide Show -->
<section id="#hpimg">
  <img class="mySlides" src="pink-velvet-cake-thumb_1_660x660.jpg" style="width:660; height: 660;">
  <img class="mySlides" src="snicker-chocolate-cake-A_660x660.jpg" style="width:660; height: 660;">
  <img class="mySlides" src="torta-unicorn.jpg" style="width:660; height: 660;">
</section>
        <script>
// Automatic Slideshow - change image every 3 seconds
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 3000);
}
</script>
        <section id="#hptext">
        <h5>welocome</h5>
        <p>fkld;flfk;sk</p>
        </section>
        </div>


    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things I notice right away:

`<section id="#hpimg">` & `<section id="#hptext">`

You'll need to remove the '#' from these id declarations in order for your CSS to affect them.

And the reason your links aren't working:
`<a herf="">...</a>`

'herf' isn't the same as 'href'. Always check for typos ;)

EDIT: It seemed like one of your edits indicated you wanted the image moved to the left instead of the right. I've updated the little [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3kz2bxqv/) I made, basically just changing `float:left` to `float:right`.

Comment: omg !! i didn't even notice that (face balm) but when i corrected the # from the id tag it removed all of my styling for those sections and the div tag :((

Comment: `<section id="hpimg">` should be the id declaration. In your CSS, you still use `#hpimg` to define the style. Basically in the html, you use words like "id" and "class" to declare the names, but in the css, you use "#" and "." respectively to refer to those declarations.

Comment: yeah yeah I did that actually but still it removed my styling

Comment: Ahh, i see. What you need here is what's known as a clearfix. When a container only has floated elements inside it, it has no idea what it's height is. You don't have to declare the height, however, if you add the following to your CSS: `hp_div:after {  content: "";  display: table;  clear: both;}` you'll find it now adjusts for the floated elements.  EDIT: Fixed a minor error.  ;)

Comment: it worked !! thank you !! but here is the thing i wanted the container to be from after the bar section till the end before the footer and the picture being on the left side and the text on the right side (i updated the question with the screen shoot to make it clearer)

Comment: The way your html is set up right now, declaring a width of 60% for `#hpimg` and 40% for `#hptext` would give you what you're looking for, I think. However, in your example the images in your carousel have a style with fixed width and height, so they could be larger or smaller than 60% of the screen-width. One solution for this would be removing the `style="..."` from the images in the carousel and add `#hpimg img { width:100%; }` to your CSS. Hopefully this gives you some ideas of how to move forward.

Comment: I'm gonna literally die! It is still not working :(((

Comment: Any way I appreciate your help really!! +I'm so sorry that I wasted your time when it is not working as I want to be :(

Comment: No apology needed. Check out the fiddle I made: [https://jsfiddle.net/de2xvc7r/](https://jsfiddle.net/de2xvc7r/) and see if that helps any.

Comment: it worrrkeeddd!! you are a life saver.one last thing and i will be good to go !! for the image i want to stick to the right side of the page i already did float:right for it but it didn't accommodate to that(please refer to the screenshot i provided above)

Comment: Here's a helful tip: Add `border:solid 1px #ff0000` to `.hp_div` and then add one to `#hpimg` but change the color to `#00ff00`. You'll now be able to see exactly where each one begins and ends. I say this because without access to all the code, I can't tell if something in your CSS is applying a margin or padding to the image or the section in question, but that would be my first guess looking at your screenshot. A `.mySlides` class style perhaps?

Comment: okay for now i will keep it like that and when i want to modify it position i will style the boarder as you said. Thank you so much for the help deeply i appreciate it !!! is there a way to communicate with you in case i get stuck at something?? since you are more experienced than me ^_^

Comment: Sorry, I can't make myself that accessible, If you get stuck again, just remember to search SO or post a new question, there are thousands of helpful, knowledgeable people who will help you out.

Comment: Wait I'm really sorry I think I made a mistake by asking that from you I'm genuinely sorry if I made uncomfortable by me request. and yes thank you for the advice I will surely be needing it as this is a new thing for me"web-based systems". And I hope God bless you and your family

Comment: No apology needed, you did nothing wrong. When I use SO to ask a question, I like to stick around and offer what little help I can for a while by answering others' questions. But I very rarely end up asking questions, so I'm not here often, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use bootstrap the col-md for the text and image
For example

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-7">
     <p> Text </p>
   </div>
   <div class="5">
     <img href="cake img">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```